# how can I launch an activity directly from my activity

Tags: android

In my android project, I have 2 Activities. How can I launch an Activity from an Activity. 
I know I can do 'startActivity', but my activity has NOT registered for any Intent, is there anyway I can still launch it from my activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class));
```

Comment: Just as a follow-up, generally the "android way" is to implement anonymous inner classes for things such as button click handlers and other things of that nature. In those cases a simple "this" will cause an error. I forced myself to get in the habit of typing the name of the class I was currently in and then "this", so if I was starting an activity from "MyMainActivity" it would read like this:

startActivity(new Intent(MyMainActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));

Comment: Also note, you won't have to list an intent filter for it, but it'll still have to be listed in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class));
```

or

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```